Storing async WebSocket messages in React state without message loss
I have a React app that connects to a WebSocket using react-use-websocket. Messages are received asynchronously, processed by receiveHandler and then the socketMessages state is updated with the response. Sample code:
import useWebSocket from 'react-use-websocket';

const [socketMessages, setSocketMessages] = useState([])
const { lastJsonMessage } = useWebSocket(path);
    
useEffect(() => {
  const processedResponse = receiveHandler(lastMessage)
  setSocketMessages([...socketMessages, processedResponse])
}, [lastMessage]);

const receiveHandler = (lastMessage) =< {
   // do receive processing on lastMessage
   return processedLastMessage
}

My issue is that messages are sometimes arriving in quick succession and new state updates are happening before existing updates are finished, causing messages to get lost.
Is there a simple way to handle this within the native functionality? Or, do i need a module to implement some form of queue?

I think you can achieve that using UseRef() and setTimeOut() with function to check if your value is updated.
This should do the purpose:
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import useWebSocket from 'react-use-websocket';
//
const WebSocketComponent = ({path}) =>{
   //
   const [socketMessage, setSocketMessage] = useState([]);
   const {lastJsonMessage} = useWebSocket(path);
   const messageQueue = useRef([])
   const processingQueue = useRef(false)
   //
   const recieveHandler = (message) =>{
   // process the received message
   // implement your message processing logic here ..
   return processedMessage;
   }
   
   
   const processQueue = () => {
      if(processingQueue.current || messageQueue.current.Length ===0){
         return;
      }
      processQueue.current = true;
      const processNextMessage = () => {
         if(messageQueue.current.Length === 0){
            processingQueue.current = false;
            return;
         }
         //
         const nextMessage = messageQueue.current.shift();
         const processedMessage = receiveHandler(nextMessage);
         //
         setSocketMessage((prevMessage)=>[...prevMessages, processedMessage]);
          // schedule the next message to be processed after the state update: 
         setTimeout(processNextMessage, 0);
      };
 
      processNextMessage();
   };
   
   useEffect(()=>{
      if(lastJsonMessage){
         messageQueue.current.push(lastJsonMessage);
         processQueue();
      }
   },[lastJsonMessage])

}

I didn't run the code in vsc so please let me know if it worked.

Thankyou - i follow the logic completely except for:
// schedule the next message to be processed after the state update:  setTimeout(processNextMessage, 0);
I can't see any logic here that is state update dependent and i'm not clear what setTimeout is doing when set to 0?

your welcome!
when you use setTimeout(fn,0) it schedules the function fn to run after the current execution stack clears and placing it at the back of event loop queue. This technique is often used to allow the browser to complete pending operations (such like handling events).
link

when you say setTimeout(processNextMessage,0); it doesn't execute 'processNextMessage' immediatley but instead it makes it run after the current call stack is complete, that makes sure that the state updates - triggered by 'setSocketMessage' - have some time to finish before the next message is processed.
